# if statement and popup case

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, popup

I have a textbox. its name is PhoneNumber. I want to do a popup if len(input value)=0.
When I do a  tag it doesn't work. (I looked in debug mode)
When I do it in an another Jq script which is already works. it works but popup window stay screen only a few mil seconds so I can not do anything. 
I am new in programming and I am still learning. İf you help me I will be happy. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#PhoneNumber').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var test = $('#PhoneNumber').val().length;
            if (test == 0) {
                alert('At Least');
                /*  $('a.login-window').one(function () {               
                    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');
                    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
                    $(loginBox2).fadeIn(300);
                    //Set the center alignment padding + border
                    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
                    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;
                    $(loginBox).css({
                        'margin-top': -popMargTop,
                        'margin-left': -popMargLeft
                    });
                    // Add the mask to body
                    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
                    return false;
                });

                // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
                $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
                    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
                        $('#mask').remove();
                    });
                    return false;
                });*/    
            }
            else 
            {
                alert('At Least');
                $("#PhoneNumber").val("");
                $('#PhoneNumber').focus();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to show us where you're calling this script , and if there are other scripts runnings.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/SgBnU/1/

Comment: Thank you my friend. I can do alert but I can not do popup. Actually popup appears but suddenly disappear. Unfortunately my problem has not been solved. My real code with popup is below (in my second comment.). If you can advice me I will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Always put your jquery code into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your code 
});
```

This makes sure that the DOM is loaded when you attach event handlers to elements.

And for me it looks like the `return false` of your `one` callback function is killing the fadeIn before it's finished.

You could add the event object `e` as a parameter of the function and then use `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;` like that:

```
$('a.login-window').one(function (e) {      
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //Your code   
});
```